# Replacing all images in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an old WordPress site with thousands of images that are not optimized; making the site run very slow. I have plans to optimize all the images and then replace the ones on the site with the new, smaller images. I don't want to upload all the images to the site in addition to having the old ones there. I want to delete the old ones and add the new ones. What is the best way that I can accomplish this without breaking things?

Comment: You can use a plugin like WP Fastest Cache, this has a feature to optimise all your images.

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP access, you could download all of your images and optimize however you see fit, then re-upload (just keep them the same dimensions & file name and override the old files). Be sure to back up any required full-size images because you're overriding the ones on the server this way and wont get them back.

Or [use one of dozens of image optimization plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/image+optimization/) so you have no need to replace any images manually. For example:

- [Smush](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)
- [Ewww](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/)
- [Imagify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagify/)
- [Kraken](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kraken-image-optimizer/)
- [CW](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cw-image-optimizer/)
- [TinyPNG](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/)